# Does technology erode the subject or inflate the subject, and , are there good refutations of David Skrbinas philosophy of technology?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-technology, hermeneutics

My question largely revolves around the work of one Chad Haag, he is a philosophy undergrad with a masters in comparative literature, he fled to India to avoid paying student loans and is a pretty prolific author, putting out about 2 books a year. His most recent book 'Hermeneutical Death' posits the following (abstract from amazon):
"Although the only acceptable criticism of Modern Technology is the Frankfurt School cliché that it makes the subject “too big” by allowing it to dominate the entire cosmos with instrumental reason, Haag argues that this academic industry caricature actually gets the problem exactly backwards. Because the self-moving simulation eventually squeezes out the possibility of interpretation, technology causes the subject to disappear through a paradoxical excess rather than lack of sensory stimulation. Through an in-depth analysis of all six somatic contexts, Haag reveals that Modern Technology is not just another Soma because it somehow oversteps its own hermeneutical limits to become something other than a counter sense object based on fossil fuels. Detailed readings of the greatest anti-technological thinkers Ted Kaczynski, Jacques Ellul, Julius Evola, Pentti Linkola, John Michael Greer, Martin Heidegger, Michael Ruppert, and John Zerzan reveal that Gadamer’s false dichotomy between sensation and language misses the point that it is precisely Technique’s excessive linguistic clarity which destroys the horizon of ecological hermeneutics. Meditations on the forbidden thinkers Sayyid Qutb, Ted Bundy, David Icke, Hans-Hermann Hoppe, and René Guénon reveal that the Power Leaked collective racks up nominally-massive accomplishments but only at the cost of degrading the individual to nothing except a cog in the System with no agency beyond feeling sensations and obeying mandates. Critiques of Social Justice Politics, as well as prominent technophiles like Ray Kurzweil, Mark Zuckerberg, and Anita Sarkeesian, expose the contradictions inherent in technological apologetics, while readings of pop culture phenomena like Star Trek, Death Note, and Marvel Comics reveal the unspeakable truth about our own technological society."

And here is a video describing the overall argument of the book:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kM6kDc7r6U

I would like to get some good criticism of the thesis, and hopefully some good criticism of the work of David Skrbina as well.

Thank you in advance for any response!